# Member from parent in derived classes interfere, depending on initialisation

Tags: python, inheritance, constructor

Why is `letters` shared between child instances below?

```
class Parent:
    letters = list()

    def add(self, letter):
        self.letters.append(letter)

class A(Parent):
    def add_a(self):
        self.add('a')

class B(Parent):
    def add_b(self):
        self.add('b')

a = A()
b = B()

a.add_a()
b.add_b()

print(a.letters)
# a.letters now contains a renegade b!
```

If I redefine `Parent` as such

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.letters = list()

    def add(self, letter):
        self.letters.append(letter)
```

`a` and `b` have separate lists of `letters`. This what I would've expected from the first code. What's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extremely frequent mistake by beginners - did it for months myself.  `letters` is assigned/bound to `class Parents`.  Anyone looking at it and modifying it is doing so on that single copy of `letters`, which is shared (you can use `print(f"{id(self.letters)=}")` to see the variable's memory allocation identifier).

Inheritance has nothing to do with it, you'd have the same effect if you created 5 instances of any of your 3 classes and started adding letters.  What happens is that `letters` is a mutable type and modifying it happily modifies the copy everyone shares even if `self.letters` makes it *seem* like a private copy.

In the 2nd case, you create a new `letters` for each new instance.  This is most likely what you want here.  By creating a new `letters` on each instance, you've avoided the unwanted sharing.

This behavior would be different if you were adding to a number or concatening to a string - those are immutable types and each instance would therefore be modifying its own local copy even if it started looking at the Parent in the first place.  (basically, it *reads* the shared copy, but it *assigns* the result of any modification to a copy of that variable bound to the `self` namespace under the same name).

See also ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Oh, and that trick about print(id(var))?  Don't rely on it to do the same with *integers under 255* - Python optimizes things under the cover by holding only 1 copy of all such variables.  `2` in 5 different variables all have the same `id` and `6` in another 4 spots have share another unique `id`.